# Are quantum experiments superdeterministic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, determinism, quantum-measurements, free-will

Lately this recent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytyjgIyegDI) of Dr. Sabine Hossenfelder made me think if this theory deserves a serious review and has substantial ground.

What are the rigorous arguments against this theory today?

Please watch this recent video first of Dr. Sabine Hossenfelder before answering.

Comment: Could you provide some information about the nature of the proposed superdeterministic theory, rather than just a video link?

Comment: If you are interested in rigorous arguments against superdeterminism, there are aren't any. However, please note that this is true for almost any empirical postulate. Non-local hidden variables, for example, also have no rigorous arguments against them. The only thing here we can use are aesthetic appeal and experiment. Sabine Hossenfelder is right to point out that almost all arguments made against superdeterminism are incredibly fallacious and non-sensical.

Comment: However, superdeterminism like many other interpretations has its own weirdness that I am surprised she didn't mention. Look into the [cosmic Bell test by Rauch, et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05966). It tells us that if the measurement settings are not statistically independent from the particles we measure, then there must be a correlations between distant quasar light in such a way that the particles somehow know about these. This is why this isn't just ordinary determinism. In a sense, it proposes that even if we choose something like weather data to set our measurement settings...

Comment: ... the weather data and the particles would somehow be deterministically correlated as to produce the Bell inequality violations. From the point of view of aesthetics, this is about as strange as many-worlds. Why should weather data (or distant quasars) and particles conspire to violate Bell's inequalities? It's possible, so there's no rigorous argument against it, but it is not a trivial suggestion. Ultimately, someone needs to propose a concrete mechanism that would explain how these correlations could be achieved, and to my mind no one has done that.

Comment: Perhaps the question may be improved by quoting (if copyright allowes) parts of the complete transcript that can be found on http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2021/12/does-superdeterminism-save-quantum.html.